# How to make shader fade by only sending data once?

Tags: opengl, shader

I am having difficulty making a square fade to black using exclusively the shaders. I am using OpenGL combined with C++ and Qt. What I need to do is send the vertex list to the GPU one time and only have one draw call. Using that one vertex list, I need the square to fade to black over a certain amount of time. Is this possible by using only OpenGL shaders? I do not want to do this on the CPU side because it is part of a larger application and makes it extremely slow. How do I make a shader fade without sending it new faded values?

Comment: You can bring it down to zero geometry uploads, one uniform upload, and one draw-call per frame but I don't think it's possible to do one draw-call per entire fade, even using the [indirect rendering](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Rendering#Indirect_rendering) (no way to trigger buffer-swaps from the GPU).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fade out effect is easy done in the fragment shader.

You have a timer in the CPU. Every time it fires you drecrease a var `remainingPercent` meaning how much of full "white" (as opposed to full black) you want to see in the window. Let this value be in range [0, 1.0].

Each time the timer fires you just bind the VAO's and call `glDrawXX`, no need to fill the buffers again. And call swapbuffers.

You pass this `remainingPercent` value by a `glUniform` to shader. The last step is mixing the current color with the full black by the amount of this uniform. Something like:

```
float uniform fadeOut;
in vec4  fragColor;
out vec4 finalColor;
....
finalColor = mix(vec4(0.0), fragColor, fadeOut);
```